# Azure Data Factory - cannot find data set associated with pipeline and data store

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-data-factory

I cannot find an output **data set** that has been created while setting up a **Copy Activity**. A data store and a pipeline are associated with this data set and thus I cannot delete them. I get the following message when trying to do so:

```
Linked service 'TestDestination' cannot be deleted as it is being referenced by 1 other objects. First reference is 'OutputDataset-bla'.
```

I cannot find this `OutputDataset-bla` anywhere. It is not in the Author and Deploy>Data sets. I also tried to search for it within Azure All Resources but nothing came out.

suggestions?

Comment: Is it within the pipeline code?  Copy Activity can generate one big JSON including datasets rather than individual objects.

Comment: I went throught the Copy Activity wizard and this output data set was autogenerated but it did not show up in the datasets section. I am not sure what you mean by pipeline code

Comment: If you look at your pipeline in the 'Author and Deploy' section you will see the raw JSON for your pipeline(s).  You will also see other datasets, linked services etc. Your missing dataset is probably referenced here somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I played with it a little and deleted the reference. now I was able to delete the entire pipeline. Thanks! you can post it as answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it within the pipeline code? Copy Activity can generate one big JSON including datasets rather than individual objects.

Look at your pipeline in the 'Author and Deploy' section you will see the raw JSON for your pipeline(s). You will also see other datasets, linked services etc. Your missing dataset is probably referenced here somewhere, and possibly within a pipeline section rather than the dataset section.